# Content height of div with overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, css

How can I find out, with javascript, the height of the content inside a div with a set height and overflow:auto?

Comment: Why would you need to know the height inside of such a div?

Comment: To listen for the scrolling position inside the div and then load more content at the bottom of that div once a user reaches a certain scrolling position. (Think facebook status feed)

Comment: you can try with the scrollHeight property (non-standard), or simply sum the height of the descendants

Comment: if you want to know where the user is looking and react to it, use the scrollTop property and the scroll event. knowing the real height is then irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

You can just wrap the content inside another div and then you can use `.offsetHeight` on this internal div...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="background-color:#EEEEEE; height:400px; overflow:auto; width:100%">
      <div id="container">
        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
        ... snip ...
        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>

setTimeout(function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    alert("Container height = " + container.offsetHeight);
}, 1000);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```